# Use Google Analytics for iPhone to track app usage - Apple Approval Criteria

Tags: iphone, google-analytics, appstore-approval

there have been some confusion about using analytics in apps. Just to make sure I got it straight:

I want to use Google Analytics in my app to track app usage (tracking what content is being viewed basically). I'm not sending any user or device data to Google.
Firstly, I understand that Google Analytics API is completely fine to be used and doesn't violate any Apple developer agreements.
Secondly, I assume that in this case (anonymously tracking app usage - no user or device data) I am allowed to use the service without the need to say anywhere in the app that analytics is being used (so the 3.3.9. of '[iOS Developer Program License Agreement](http://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/standard/ios_standard_agreement_20110215.pdf)' doesn't apply here).

Can anyone confirm my assumptions or explain if they are not right?
Or better **did anyone of you have your app using analytics approved even though it didn't say anywhere it is using it?** ...or the opposite

I've seen plenty of forum entries on the subject none of them though clearly stating what is required by Apple and what is just recommended.

Thanks

Comment: I was worried about using google analytics as well after reading all guidelines and documentatio. But yesterday I had my first app that uses google analytics approved in the app store and it seems that the approval happened without any worries. So, I think there is no problem with using it for traffic analysis

Comment: Update: I've got an app approved in AppStore that is using Google Analytics and it doesn't communicate to the user anywhere that it is doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're asking about Google Analytics, but for what it's worth, I've had great success using the Flurry analytics package in my apps. It's very stable and provides a lot of great metrics. If GA doesn't work out for you, I'd say give this a try:

http://www.flurry.com/

Comment: Thanks, that's useful info. Do you mention anywhere in your apps UI that they are being tracked?

Comment: I do not and have never received flak from Apple about it.